# Dumping the stack and exceptions in case of crash in Swift

Tags: objective-c, swift

I am a newbie on Swift.

When I have a really hard bug to crack on `Objective-C` I generally replace my `main.m` file with something like this:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  int retVal;
  @autoreleasepool {
    @try {
      retVal = UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, nil); //***
    }
    @catch (NSException *exception) {
      NSLog(@"\n\nSTACK SYMBOLS\n%@",[exception callStackSymbols]);
      NSLog(@"\n\nSTACK RETURN ADDRESSES\n%@",
                  [exception callStackReturnAddresses]);
      NSLog(@"\n\nOBJECT: %@",[exception name]);
      NSLog(@"\n\nUSER INFO DICT: %@",[exception userInfo]);
      NSLog(@"\n\nREASON: %@",[exception reason]);
      retVal = 1;
    }
  }
  return retVal;
}
```

This will help to gather informations about a crash.

When the app crashes, the code will dump the stack, the return addresses and a lot of information that help to identify the offending lines.

Is there something like that can be done for `Swift`?

Comment: Update your question with your attempted conversion to Swift.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no real equivalent to this pattern in pure Swift because there is no equivalent to `@try` in Swift. (Swift2's `try` is unrelated and radically different in usage and implementation.)

That said, there is a way to override program launch. From the [Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Attributes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH35-ID347):

> UIApplicationMain
>
> Apply this attribute to a class to indicate that it is the application delegate. Using this attribute is equivalent to calling the UIApplicationMain function and passing this class’s name as the name of the delegate class.
>
> If you do not use this attribute, supply a main.swift file with a main function that calls the `UIApplicationMain(_:_:_:)` function. For example, if your app uses a custom subclass of UIApplication as its principal class, call the `UIApplicationMain(_:_:_:)` function instead of using this attribute.

So you can delete the `UIApplicationMain` from the application delegate, and create a `swift.main` file as described. But you can't catch exceptions there.

But you of course could just use your above `main.m` in ObjC, and it'll work the same way. Just delete the `UIApplicationMain` attribute.

(Most of what you're doing here looks very similar to what you get normally from a crash stack. Does this really give you better information that a standard crash report?)

Comment: sometimes it does. I use this when Xcode gives no clue about the problem and sometimes it works by giving me something that helps identifying the problem. Thanks.